# How to sort a PHP Array with values as strings that are split by '-'

Tags: php, sorting

I have the below array :

```
array (
  0 => '4-0',
  1 => '4-1',
  2 => '4-2',
  3 => '4-3',
  4 => '4-4',
  5 => '4-5',
  6 => '4-6',
  7 => '4-7',
  8 => '4-8',
  9 => '4-9',
  10 => '4-10',
  11 => '4-11',
  12 => '4-12',
  13 => '4-13',
  14 => '4-14',
  15 => '4-15',
  16 => '4-16',
  17 => '8-0',
  18 => '9-0',
  19 => '2-0',
  20 => '5-0',
  21 => '7-1',
)
```

What i want is to order `ASC` by `value`. So the value at array[19] should be the first one and value at array[18] the last one. I have tried some sorting functions such as `asort()` but it is not doing what i exactly want.

`asort()` :

```
array (
  0 => '2-0',
  1 => '4-0',
  2 => '4-1',
  3 => '4-10',
  4 => '4-11',
  5 => '4-12',
  6 => '4-13',
  7 => '4-14',
  8 => '4-15',
  9 => '4-16',
  10 => '4-2',
  11 => '4-3',
  12 => '4-4',
  13 => '4-5',
  14 => '4-6',
  15 => '4-7',
  16 => '4-8',
  17 => '4-9',
  18 => '5-0',
  19 => '7-1',
  20 => '8-0',
  21 => '9-0',
)
```

Is there a specific PHP Function for this or should i implement my own algorithm? Any ideas?

Comment: Guess you wanna implement something on your own... If you had the number after - with a leading 0, it would have been better, you can combine them and convert it into an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag for this:

```
<?php
$array = array (
  0 => '4-0',
  1 => '4-1',
  2 => '4-2',
  3 => '4-3',
  4 => '4-4',
  5 => '4-5',
  6 => '4-6',
  7 => '4-7',
  8 => '4-8',
  9 => '4-9',
  10 => '4-10',
  11 => '4-11',
  12 => '4-12',
  13 => '4-13',
  14 => '4-14',
  15 => '4-15',
  16 => '4-16',
  17 => '8-0',
  18 => '9-0',
  19 => '2-0',
  20 => '5-0',
  21 => '7-1',
);

sort( $array, SORT_NATURAL );
print_r( $array );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2-0
    [1] => 4-0
    [2] => 4-1
    [3] => 4-2
    [4] => 4-3
    [5] => 4-4
    [6] => 4-5
    [7] => 4-6
    [8] => 4-7
    [9] => 4-8
    [10] => 4-9
    [11] => 4-10
    [12] => 4-11
    [13] => 4-12
    [14] => 4-13
    [15] => 4-14
    [16] => 4-15
    [17] => 4-16
    [18] => 5-0
    [19] => 7-1
    [20] => 8-0
    [21] => 9-0
)
```

Comment: I hate it when someone types faster than I do!

Comment: Given the input data `natsort` is probably more efficient.

Comment: Or simply `sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);`, skips the `array_values()` step

Comment: @rickdenhaan One line solution! Thanks

Comment: @rickdenhaan I like it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `natsort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php.
It will sort the array content as string.

```
natsort($your_array)
```

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, just *sort* function will do the job.

```
sort($array);
```

Please note, Parameter is pass by reference and not pass by value.

```
<?php
$array=array (
  0 => '4-0',
  1 => '4-1',
  2 => '4-2',
  ....
  ....
);
sort($array);
print_r($array);
?>
```

Will give the same answer

Comment: Please add comment if you do a negative rating.

Comment: I did not downvote you but please expand your test case to include `4-9` and `4-10`. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5eea17ace4380ee55991ab8775d502f9c439bd68